# Calculating years/months/days between dates

Tags: php, date

```
$date1 = "2000-01-01";
$date2 = "2011-03-14";

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$years = floor($diff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
$months = ceil(($diff - ($years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / ((365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 12));
$months2 = floor(($diff - ($years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / ((365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 12));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months2 * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24)/ (60 * 60 * 24));
```

The answer I get is `11 years , 2 months and 14 days`. Shouldn't it be `11 years, 3 months and 14 days`?

I have tried quite a few different ways and I always end up with 2 months instead of 3. Does anyone know why?

Comment: why would it be 3 months? less than 90 days have passed so its < 3 months

Comment: Why do you think it should be 3 months? After all the difference between 1 and 3 is 2.. If anything, it should be 2 months and *13 days*.. Btw. date differences are always difficult, and depend on the definition of a "month"..

Comment: I see only two months between your dates: Januar & Februar. Why do you think there should be three?

Comment: Difference is `11 years 2 months and 16 days` because of 3 leap years (2000, 2004 and 2008).

Comment: @M42: That was what I meant with depends on the definition ;) Personally I wouldn't give you that answer when you asked me for the date difference of those two dates, but it is in the same way just as valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer that you are getting is completely right!

Comment: *head whack* .....of course...what the hell was i thinking!!!! my client got my entire head screwed!!! thanks for the clarity

Answer (score 8):

Try using PHP's built-in date API instead of doing the math yourself.

Using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and the [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2000-01-01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2011-03-14");
$diff = $date2->diff($date1);
var_dump($diff);'
/* is prints: 
object(DateInterval)#3 (8) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(11)
  ["m"]=>
  int(2)
  ["d"]=>
  int(13)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(1)
  ["days"]=>
  int(4090)
}
*/
```

At least then you don't need to worry if you made an error (the result seems correct).

Comment: i have only 5.2 i believe it works with only 5.3..i could be wrong on that...i tried it yesterday and it didnt work..and that was hte explanation i got...but thanks anyways solved the issue...